# OnTriggerEvent doesn't detect some objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have object (ball) that is prefab initialized on game start. On that prefab i have Script, Mesh renderer and Sphere collider. Now when i cast my `Spell`, it is normally colliding with me and `OnTriggerEvent` detect character (me) but not the ball. Why is that?

If you need any part of code or something ask me.

Comment: Does the ball has a RigidBody?

Comment: Do you have `isTrigger` enabled on your sphere collider?

Comment: Please post your code, with such few info it's impossible to answer correctly.

Comment: Hmmm I tried RigidBody and it works but i do not get the logic. Why does it need rigidbody if it has collider?

Comment: for a trigger event to happen one of the colliders must have a rigidbody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Trigger, you have to keep in mind this table
[image]

*Ensure that isTriggerEnter is checked on ball.*
[ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is something i need for now and future. I also read ref now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your ball is on a different layer that does not collide with your default layer? check your layer settings